# SIM card detection and Battery Drain - MI Redmi Note 3

Tags: battery

My MI Redmi Note 3 is not detecting the SIM card and the battery is getting drained in 15 mins simultaneously. Cannot connect to Wi-Fi too. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The only likely solution is to take it in for repair or replacement. This sounds very much like a short somewhere in the hardware.